# Clear typeahead after onSelect

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I have used [typeahead](http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/) on my project and is working ok.  Now, I have created a list so that a selection from typehead will be added into that list.  That is working fine as well.  Problem is after adding the selected item to the list, I have to manually delete the previous selection from the input.  `.val("")` apparently doesn't work on typeahead.

Here is my code:

```
var $songlist = $('#song-list tr'),
        $counter = 1,
        $typeahead = $('input.typeahead');

    $typeahead.typeahead({
        ajax: "{{ url('/admin/music/typeahead') }}",
        onSelect:function(item) {
            //console.log(item);
            $songlist.append("<td>"+
                    $counter + '. ' + item.text +
                "</td>"
            );
           $typeahead.val(''); // -> does not work
        }
    });
```

Comment: try using this.val('')

Comment: That doesn't work as well.  I found a little hack though using the same `val('')` inside a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `typeahead.js`,  find the below code and replace :

> this.$element
>   .val(this.updater(text))
>   .change();

with an empty string like  :

> this.$element
>   .val(this.updater(' '))
>   .change();

as I've shown in following code

```
Typeahead.prototype = {
        constructor: Typeahead,
        //=============================================================================================================
        //  Utils
        //  Check if an event is supported by the browser eg. 'keypress'
        //  * This was included to handle the "exhaustive deprecation" of jQuery.browser in jQuery 1.8
        //=============================================================================================================
        eventSupported: function (eventName) {
            var isSupported = (eventName in this.$element);

            if (!isSupported) {
                this.$element.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
                isSupported = typeof this.$element[eventName] === 'function';
            }

            return isSupported;
        },
        select: function () {
            var $selectedItem = this.$menu.find('.active');
            if($selectedItem.length) {
                var value = $selectedItem.attr('data-value');
                var text = this.$menu.find('.active a').text();

                if (this.options.onSelect) {
                    this.options.onSelect({
                        value: value,
                        text: text
                    });
                }
                this.$element
                    .val(this.updater(text)) //here you need to pass empty string
                    .change();
            }
            return this.hide();
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            return item;
        },
        show: function () {
            var pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.position(), {
                height: this.$element[0].offsetHeight
            });

            this.$menu.css({
                top: pos.top + pos.height,
                left: pos.left
            });

            if(this.options.alignWidth) {
                var width = $(this.$element[0]).outerWidth();
                this.$menu.css({
                    width: width
                });
            }

            this.$menu.show();
            this.shown = true;
            return this;
        },
        hide: function () {
            this.$menu.hide();
            this.shown = false;
            return this;
        },
        ajaxLookup: function () {

            var query = $.trim(this.$element.val());

            if (query === this.query) {
                return this;
            }

            // Query changed
            this.query = query;

            // Cancel last timer if set
            if (this.ajax.timerId) {
                clearTimeout(this.ajax.timerId);
                this.ajax.timerId = null;
            }

            if (!query || query.length < this.ajax.triggerLength) {
                // cancel the ajax callback if in progress
                if (this.ajax.xhr) {
                    this.ajax.xhr.abort();
                    this.ajax.xhr = null;
                    this.ajaxToggleLoadClass(false);
                }

                return this.shown ? this.hide() : this;
            }

            function execute() {
                this.ajaxToggleLoadClass(true);

                // Cancel last call if already in progress
                if (this.ajax.xhr)
                    this.ajax.xhr.abort();

                var params = this.ajax.preDispatch ? this.ajax.preDispatch(query) : {
                    query: query
                };
                this.ajax.xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: this.ajax.url,
                    data: params,
                    success: $.proxy(this.ajaxSource, this),
                    type: this.ajax.method || 'get',
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
                this.ajax.timerId = null;
            }

            // Query is good to send, set a timer
            this.ajax.timerId = setTimeout($.proxy(execute, this), this.ajax.timeout);

            return this;
        },
        ajaxSource: function (data) {
            this.ajaxToggleLoadClass(false);
            var that = this, items;
            if (!that.ajax.xhr)
                return;
            if (that.ajax.preProcess) {
                data = that.ajax.preProcess(data);
            }
            // Save for selection retreival
            that.ajax.data = data;

            // Manipulate objects
            items = that.grepper(that.ajax.data) || [];
            if (!items.length) {
                return that.shown ? that.hide() : that;
            }

            that.ajax.xhr = null;
            return that.render(items.slice(0, that.options.items)).show();
        },
        ajaxToggleLoadClass: function (enable) {
            if (!this.ajax.loadingClass)
                return;
            this.$element.toggleClass(this.ajax.loadingClass, enable);
        },
        lookup: function (event) {
            var that = this, items;
            if (that.ajax) {
                that.ajaxer();
            }
            else {
                that.query = that.$element.val();

                if (!that.query) {
                    return that.shown ? that.hide() : that;
                }

                items = that.grepper(that.source);


                if (!items) {
                    return that.shown ? that.hide() : that;
                }
                //Bhanu added a custom message- Result not Found when no result is found
                if (items.length == 0) {
                    items[0] = {'id': -21, 'name': "Result not Found"}
                }
                return that.render(items.slice(0, that.options.items)).show();
            }
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
            return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase());
        },
        sorter: function (items) {
            if (!this.options.ajax) {
                var beginswith = [],
                    caseSensitive = [],
                    caseInsensitive = [],
                    item;

                while (item = items.shift()) {
                    if (!item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()))
                        beginswith.push(item);
                    else if (~item.indexOf(this.query))
                        caseSensitive.push(item);
                    else
                        caseInsensitive.push(item);
                }

                return beginswith.concat(caseSensitive, caseInsensitive);
            } else {
                return items;
            }
        },
        highlighter: function (item) {
            var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
            if (item != undefined)
                return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
                    return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
                });
            else
                return 'No matches found!';
        },
        render: function (items) {
            var that = this, display, isString = typeof that.options.displayField === 'string';

            items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
                if (typeof item === 'object') {
                    display = isString ? item[that.options.displayField] : that.options.displayField(item);
                    i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item[that.options.valueField]);
                } else {
                    display = item;
                    i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item);
                }
                i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(display));
                return i[0];
            });

            if(that.autoSelect){
                items.first().addClass('active');
            }

            this.$menu.html(items);
            return this;
        },
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Filters relevent results
        //
        grepper: function (data) {
            var that = this, items, display, isString = typeof that.options.displayField === 'string';

            if (isString && data && data.length) {
                if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(that.options.displayField)) {
                    items = $.grep(data, function (item) {
                        display = isString ? item[that.options.displayField] : that.options.displayField(item);
                        return that.matcher(display);
                    });
                } else if (typeof data[0] === 'string') {
                    items = $.grep(data, function (item) {
                        return that.matcher(item);
                    });
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
            return this.sorter(items);
        },
        next: function (event) {
            var active = this.$menu.find('.active').removeClass('active'),
                next = active.next();

            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this.$menu.find('li')[0]);
            }

            if (this.options.scrollBar) {
                var index = this.$menu.children("li").index(next);
                if (index % 8 == 0) {
                    this.$menu.scrollTop(index * 26);
                }
            }

            next.addClass('active');
        },
        prev: function (event) {
            var active = this.$menu.find('.active').removeClass('active'),
                prev = active.prev();

            if (!prev.length) {
                prev = this.$menu.find('li').last();
            }

            if (this.options.scrollBar) {

                var $li = this.$menu.children("li");
                var total = $li.length - 1;
                var index = $li.index(prev);

                if ((total - index) % 8 == 0) {
                    this.$menu.scrollTop((index - 7) * 26);
                }

            }

            prev.addClass('active');

        },
        listen: function () {
            this.$element
                .on('focus', $.proxy(this.focus, this))
                .on('blur', $.proxy(this.blur, this))
                .on('keypress', $.proxy(this.keypress, this))
                .on('keyup', $.proxy(this.keyup, this));

            if (this.eventSupported('keydown')) {
                this.$element.on('keydown', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
            }

            this.$menu
                .on('click', $.proxy(this.click, this))
                .on('mouseenter', 'li', $.proxy(this.mouseenter, this))
                .on('mouseleave', 'li', $.proxy(this.mouseleave, this))
        },
        move: function (e) {
            if (!this.shown)
                return

            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 9: // tab
                case 13: // enter
                case 27: // escape
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break

                case 38: // up arrow
                    e.preventDefault()
                    this.prev()
                    break

                case 40: // down arrow
                    e.preventDefault()
                    this.next()
                    break
            }

            e.stopPropagation();
        },
        keydown: function (e) {
            this.suppressKeyPressRepeat = ~$.inArray(e.keyCode, [40, 38, 9, 13, 27])
            this.move(e)
        },
        keypress: function (e) {
            if (this.suppressKeyPressRepeat)
                return
            this.move(e)
        },
        keyup: function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 40: // down arrow
                case 38: // up arrow
                case 16: // shift
                case 17: // ctrl
                case 18: // alt
                    break

                case 9: // tab
                case 13: // enter
                    if (!this.shown)
                        return
                    this.select()
                    break

                case 27: // escape
                    if (!this.shown)
                        return
                    this.hide()
                    break

                default:
                    if (this.ajax)
                        this.ajaxLookup()
                    else
                        this.lookup()
            }

            e.stopPropagation()
            e.preventDefault()
        },
        focus: function (e) {
            this.focused = true
        },
        blur: function (e) {
            this.focused = false
            if (!this.mousedover && this.shown)
                this.hide()
        },
        click: function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            e.preventDefault()
            this.select()
            this.$element.focus()
        },
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            this.mousedover = true
            this.$menu.find('.active').removeClass('active')
            $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active')
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
            this.mousedover = false
            if (!this.focused && this.shown)
                this.hide()
        },
        destroy: function() {
            this.$element
                .off('focus', $.proxy(this.focus, this))
                .off('blur', $.proxy(this.blur, this))
                .off('keypress', $.proxy(this.keypress, this))
                .off('keyup', $.proxy(this.keyup, this));

            if (this.eventSupported('keydown')) {
                this.$element.off('keydown', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
            }

            this.$menu
                .off('click', $.proxy(this.click, this))
                .off('mouseenter', 'li', $.proxy(this.mouseenter, this))
                .off('mouseleave', 'li', $.proxy(this.mouseleave, this))
            this.$element.removeData('typeahead');
        }
    };`enter code here`
```